# Nextjs container lazy loading

Tags: next.js

In the Nextjs, for optimizations purposes, an image won't load until the user reaches its boundary view. So basically, by the time the user scroll the page to the boundary of the image, the image won't load.

This cause me some issues with my **Slider**.

I am using the library `react-responsive-carousel` to show some images in a slider.
These images are shown only in mobile view. That means, if the user enters the page with a desktop view, I don't want the slider's images to load because the user won't see these images anyway.
That's why I've configured those images with the Nextjs lazy loading configuration.

However, this cause some problems. If the user does enter the page within a mobile view, he may scroll to the slider - then **only the first image loads, and the rest (which are not visible yet) won't load**. This causes the issue: when the user flicks the slider, the slider shows the next image. **Only then - Nextjs with load this image** - and then - the user sees a blur effect.

I want all the slider's images to lazy loading at once, when the user scrolls to this slider. So not only the first image (that is really shown) to load, but even when first image is shown, I want Nextjs to start loading all the slider's images (even thought these are yet to be shown).

Is it possible?

This is my slider container:

```
return (
    <Carousel
        className={classes['carousel']}
        selectedItem={props.selectedItemIndex}
        showThumbs={false}
        showStatus={false}
        renderIndicator={renderIndicator}
        renderArrowPrev={renderArrowPrev}
        renderArrowNext={renderArrowNext}
    >
        <DoingItCarouselItem
            image={browseImg}
            title={t('doingIt.browse.title')}
            text={<Trans i18nKey="doingIt.browse.description" />}
        />
        <DoingItCarouselItem
            image={searchImg}
            title={t('doingIt.search.title')}
            text={<Trans i18nKey="doingIt.search.description" />}
        />
        <DoingItCarouselItem
            image={pileUpImg}
            title={t('doingIt.pileUp.title')}
            text={<Trans i18nKey="doingIt.pileUp.description" />}
        />
        <DoingItCarouselItem
            image={personalizedImg}
            title={t('doingIt.personalizedExperience.title')}
            text={<Trans i18nKey="doingIt.personalizedExperience.description" />}
        />
        <DoingItCarouselItem
            image={sellerImg}
            title={t('doingIt.trustedSellers.title')}
            text={<Trans i18nKey="doingIt.trustedSellers.description" />}
        />
    </Carousel>
);
```

And this is the item component:

```
return (
    <div className={classes['container']}>
        <div className={classes['container__img']}>
            <Image
                src={props.image}
                alt={props.title}
                placeholder="blur"
                objectFit="contain"
                layout="fill"
            />
        </div>
        <h4 className={classes['container__title']}>{props.title}</h4>
        <span className={classes['container__text']}>{props.text}</span>
    </div>
);
```

Just for illustration, full code was not provided.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Is this possibly a lazy invocation thing? i.e. src={() => props.image}